# create animation in android

Tags: android, imageview

I need to create an animation in android,i have one fixed image in the screen, i need to add another image over the old image in 5 to 10 second interval.

i have searched and i found something like this

[how-to-change-images-on-imageview-after-some-interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167541/how-to-change-images-on-imageview-after-some-interval)

but here they have used the array list of images but i need to add only single image within some interval.

Could somebody help me @Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601318/setbackgroundresource-doesnt-set-the-image/16602220#16602220. Check this might help you

Comment: in the link i have set a default image and the other image replaces the old one every few seconds. So every few seconds it switches between those 2 images in imageview. What do you mean by overlapping imageview?

Comment: @Raghunandan but actually my question is i have an fixed image in the xml ,i need to overlap another another in few interval

Comment: yup you can use the code in the link for the same

Comment: I think You should use FRAME BY FRAME animation....

Comment: @RINK how could i make it