# Android ImageView not refreshing

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view

I have created four ImageViews dynamicly, when I click a button I want to change each image after one second, but they all change after four seconds. Can anyone give me a suggestion as to the problem?

```
public void Run_Click(View view) {
    int j=10;
    try {
        while(true) {
             if(j<14) {
                 im=(ImageView)findViewById(j);
                 im.setImageResource(R.drawable.open);
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                 j++;
             } else {
                 j=10;
                 for(int i=10;i<14;i++) {
                     im=(ImageView)findViewById(i);
                     im.setImageResource(R.drawable.close);
                 }
                 Thread.sleep(2000);
              }
    }
```

Comment: I hope you did sleep not in UI Thread? If not in UI thread than you cannot modify UI elements from that thread.

Answer (score 1):

You are sleeping in the UI thread and that just a very bad approach.

Please have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html#addFrame%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20int%29):

> public void addFrame (Drawable frame, int duration)
>
> Added in API level 1 Add a frame to the animation
>
> Parameters frame  The frame to add duration   How long in milliseconds
> the frame should appear

and use the addFrame method.

You just have to specify a Drawable and a duration.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use thread.sleep() its a bad design approach. Calling thread.sleep() on the ui thread is bad design. Even if you use a thread do some computation do not use thread.sleep().

If you implement Thread or HandlerThread, be sure that your UI thread does not block while waiting for the worker thread to complete—**do not call Thread.wait() or Thread.sleep()**. Instead of blocking while waiting for a worker thread to complete, your main thread should provide a Handler for the other threads to post back to upon completion.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

You can try few options mentioned in the link like handler, animation drawable and timer task

[setBackgroundResource doesn't set the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601318/setbackgroundresource-doesnt-set-the-image/16602220#16602220)