# ImageSwitcher displays image before animating it

Tags: android, imageswitcher

I am a beginner when it comes to these things, so apologies if this is a simple question.

I am attempting to implement the ImageSwitcher to cycle through a set of images.  To do this, I'm trying to implement the timer as described here: [How to make an ImageSwitcher switch the image every 5 secs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583742/how-to-make-an-imageswitcher-switch-the-image-every-5-secs)

I have got the images cycling through just fine, however the image loads and then the animation takes place.  Image 1 will be displayed then it will switch to image 2 then fade out image 2 and fade it back in again. Image 2 will then be displayed for the specified time, and the process repeats.

I want Image 1 to fade out, and then fade Image 2 in.

Here is what I have so far:

```
imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.welcome_image);
    imageSwitcher.setFactory(this);
    imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
    imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out));
```

The timer from the aforementioned question:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
  //Set the schedule function and rate
  t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
public void run() {
          //Called each time when 1000 milliseconds (1 second) (the period parameter)
          currentIndex++;
        // If index reaches maximum reset it
         if(currentIndex==messageCount)
             currentIndex=0;
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {


                imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imageIDs[currentIndex]);

            }
      });
      }

  },1000,5000);
```

And

```
public View makeView() {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    return imageView;
}
```

I would dearly appreciate some assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting setInAnimation() 2 times. You didn't set setOutAnimation().

Like:

```
imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,   
android.R.anim.fade_out));
```